# What negative values in LUT mean and how to use them?

Tags: image-processing, fragment-shader, lookup-tables

I am rewriting fragment shader to be able to use the data from `.cube` look up texture files.

It looks straightforward as everything I need seems to be to create new uniform 3D texture sampler and mix the appropriate value contained in the LUT file with the fragment shader outputColour value.

But what I really do not understand is why the LUT file contains negative RGB float values and how to approach them.
Does it mean when lets say the data row in LUT looks like:

`0.1201138 0.0000000 -0.0063639`

And original outputColour was e.g.:

`vec3 = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 }`

Then after applying the exact LUT data row on this outputColour I should get:

outputColour = {

`0.5 + 0.5 * 0.1201138`, -> positive value thus positive colour gain `R`

`0.5 + 0.5 * 0.0000000`, -> 0 thus neutral gain in `G`

`0.5 + 0.5 * -0.0063639` -> negative value thus negative colour gain in `B`

}

Is it really like this or my assumptions are wrong and I missuse the the LUT file?

Comment: But when I think about it - I maybe missinterpreted the LUT data as the row stored in the file should not mean how to alter the existing colour value, but how to substitute the original colour, but then I feel like I get it less and less, as the negative values do not make any sense at all then...